# NodeJS- get process ID from within shell script exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, pid

I have some NodeJS code which runs a shell script using `child_process.exec()`. Within this shell script I run a program `someProgram`. What I would like to do is get the PID of `someProgram` and pass that back into my Javascript code so I can later kill that specific process with another `child_process.exec()` call. Is this possible?

Comment: Does your shell script opens the program as a separate process? If it doesn't, can't you use child_process.pid ?

Comment: My shell script runs the program as a background process. Won't child_process.pid just get me the pid of the shell script and not the program within it?

Comment: Yes you are correct, that's what I was trying to ask. I know that in C you can use 'pipe' to pass data between processes, perhaps once the shell scripts spawns the separate process, you could pass the pid using a pipe to the JS?
I haven't done this with node so not sure whether possible or most elegant way of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var pid = {};
exec('. ./script.sh', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(stdout);
  setTimeout(function() {
    exec('kill ' + pid, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log(stdout);
    });
  }, 6000);

});

exec('pgrep -f someProgram', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log('stdout' + stdout);
  pid = stdout;
  console.log('pid ' + pid);
});
```

just note that the bottom exec would run concurrently. You could use this in a gulpfile, etc.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to get the pid of a process created by a child process.

Comment: var child = exec(...);
pid=child.pid; 
.. this will return the pid the process got.